# See Download progress

Tags: 14.04, firefox, downloads

How can I see download progress in Firefox in Ubuntu 14.04 ?? I can see download progress in windows using CTRL + J shortcut key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>

or Tools -> Downloads

Comment: Or click on the Downloads button in the toolbar/menu. If you hold the pointer over the button, a tooltip should appear showing the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I don't actually see a progress bar here. I see "Filename.pdf.part" and "Filename.pdf". When it is done, the .part file disappears so you know it is done but again, no progress.